# Google Sign In with firebase on android keeps failing

Tags: android, firebase

I have spent the whole day trying to get my anroid app to sign in using firebase. But no turtorial solved my problem.

I have a firebase Project, and the SHA1 was updated.

I used this code [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

The exception only says login faild. I thougt the problem might be the pre installed google app on the emulator, so I tried it on another device, didn't help. I wiped the data on all emulators, didn't help.

What else could I try? Did you have the same problem, how did you solve it?

**Edit:**

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests from this Android client application ch.workouttracker are blocked. ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzto.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzux.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuu.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:25)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztl.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpm.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:23)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzul.zzq(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpt.zzA(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztp.zzv(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsb.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsa.accept(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacj.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zah.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:193)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:158)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zap(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:120)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zao(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:38)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:17)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zag.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:24)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:11)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.5.0:49)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: Something "funny" i found, when the emulator runs SDK 31 it is failing later then when i use SDK 27

Comment: I created a new google account for testing - i do not get the window to select the account i want to use

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-installations/API_KEY_RESTRICTIONS.md#what-do-i-need-to-do)

The problem is a bug in the Firebase API, this is only a workaround.

It took me only a few days...